# Javascript returning Null value in object

Tags: javascript, api, object

I am using the following code to call an API and return results:

```
api.jobs.all(function(response) {

const obj = response.data.map(function(item) {
    return [item.id, item.billed.amountString];

});
});
```

With the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
     "id": 2090170,
     "deadline": null,
     "jobId": {
        "id": 1644
     },
     "billed": {
        "amountString": 200,
        "currencyType": "CAD"
     }
    },
    {
     "id": 2090171,
     "deadline": null,
     "jobId": {
        "id": 1645
     },
     "billed": {
        "amountString": 400,
        "currencyType": "USD"
     }
}]}
```

The code is working fine, for the most part I am getting back good results, with the exception of: **billed.amountString**

I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'amountString' of null

Can anyone see why this would be returning null?

Also, is there a way in which I could loop through the API call and force it to do the following:

```
If .amountString === null, .amountString = "";
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You have a single object in your array, which has two properties with the key "id".

Comment: Sorry, typo. I've updated the post.

Comment: You should re-check your JSON data, you have a single object inside a the data array, which contains duplicate properties, that I presume are supposed to be a part of a separate object in the array.

Comment: It was a typo as per above, I've updated the post.

Comment: With that exact JSON, are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes, still the same error which is weird. All other values and keys will return fine.

Comment: I've tried your code - no error

Comment: I even tried to add an additional id in the array where "amountString" is completely missing.
`console.table(json.data.map(function(i) { return [i.id, i.billed.amountString]; })); ` lists a table having no errors.

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hirsche/gov0b1qo/)

Comment: My JSON is larger than this, however cannot see any instances where billed.amountString does not exist. Is there a good way to loop through to check?

Comment: @JimDover I've updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hirsche/gov0b1qo/) to see which amountString is undefined. It's done quick and dirty ... just to see for what **ids** it is null or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var response = {
  "data": [
  {
     "id": 2090170,
     "deadline": null,
     "jobId": {
        "id": 1644
     },
     "billed": {
        "amountString": 200,
        "currencyType": "CAD"
     }
    },
    {
     "id": 2090171,
     "deadline": null,
     "jobId": {
        "id": 1645
     },
     "billed": {
        "amountString": 400,
        "currencyType": "USD"
     }
}]};

const obj = (response.data).map(function(item) {
    return [item.id, item.billed.amountString];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I am glad that it resolved your problem. Thank you for asking this question. It helped me to brush up my concepts too :p

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library `lodash`. The lodash method `get` can be used to try and access an object field. If it does not exist you can specify a default return value. See https://lodash.com/ .

```
// This will try to access item.billed.amountString
// If an item does not exist anywhere along the way
// it will return the default.

// _.get( OBJECT, PATH, DEFAULT )
_.get(item, ['billed', 'amountString'], '')
```